# 'The following arguments were not expected: environment.yml --file create' when making new Mamba environment

Tags: deep-learning, conda, mamba

I need to test the model described in the [IceNet paper](https://github.com/tom-andersson/icenet-paper) but I am having issues making the Mamba environment.

After installing Mamba as described [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge), if I run the command `mamba env create --name esports --file environment.yml` I get the error `The following arguments were not expected: environment.yml --file create Run with --help for more information.`

Is there a way I can fix that? Also, I am working with an A100 GPU. Does it still make sense to use Mamba (the code was originally developed to run on a laptop) or am I already fine using Conda as usual?

Comment: This sounds like a typo. Please show the actual shell commands and results in sequence, formatted in a code block, rather than interspersed with prose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mamba should have the same API as Conda so the command yo tried should be correct. The error you get is likely due to a typo.

Note that I was able to trigger this exact error using [Micromamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/micromamba.html) which has a different API than Mamba. Micromamba only has the `micromamba create` command that handles both YAML and list environment files. In that case, the correct command is:

```
micromamba create --name esports --file environment.yml
```

Comment: @merv It looks like I based my answer on micromamba, which I thought has the same API as mamba, which is wrong (micromamba only have `micromamba create` which works for both YAML and list env). I'll correct my answer.